# Comment removed with no explanation

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, deleted-comments

Can a moderator explain why my comment was removed from this post? I posted "what effort have you made?"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585727/comparing-mobile-and-desktop-app-performance-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment54947664_33585727

Comment: It probably fell victim to flags given that's it not a very constructive comment.

Comment: Related:  ["What have you tried" epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172758/175248) on Meta.SE.

Comment: It is a bit of a toss-up what is more absurd.  Expecting a response to such a comment, flagging the comment, deleting the comment or crowd-sourcing 3 lines of code.  I have to go for the latter.

Comment: The original Q was flawed. You tried to get it narrowed in. I can see no votes for a comment... but to get it removed does seem harsh.  SO is harsher than ever, even this benign Q is -4 at the moment.  It's like nerd bullying. I hope SO hasn't jumped the shark.

Comment: Well, the question the comment was on is gone now too. Good riddance to it, as the answer to your comment shows no promise of getting anywhere anytime.

Answer (score 2):

As general policy, comments asking, "what have you tried" (or the moral equivalent) will be deleted because they're not specific enough.  It's typically not helpful to the question author because they don't know what information you're looking for.

The mods will be looking for you to tailor the comment to the question, asking for specific pieces of information that are missing *for that question* rather than something that could be (and in fact is) on the "how to ask" page of the help center.