# Comments Vanishing

Tags: discussion

On this question: [What are the valid characters in PHP namespace names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027816/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-php-namespace-names/41027864?noredirect=1#41027816)

I made several comments to both the question and the answer in the spirit of helping improve both for future visitors.

The question was edited (although it did not take into account my comments, as far as I can tell).

The answer comments were vaped, although they **clearly** helped shape the answer's current form.

Two questions:

1. How can I see - other than my comments vanishing - what / why that happened?
2. Under what circumstances can someone simply vape comments like that?

NOTE:
I've seen [comments removed with no explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309639/comment-removed-with-no-explanation) and [comment explaining downvote keeps being deleted- why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258605/comment-explaining-downvote-keeps-on-being-deleted-why), but neither speak to the circumstances that I observed.

Also - this happened in a **very short** amount of time (seconds - definitely less than 2-3 minutes), so flags / moderation seems unlikely.

Comment: That, and a diamond moderator has left a comment on that post.

Comment: No, only diamond mods can. The exception being multiple flags from other users and dupe vote comments (both of which are unlikely in this case)

Comment: @cale_b It's likely the comments were flagged to get the mod's attention, but yes.

Comment: the PHP tag just so happens to be a frequent destination of the given mod. They likely came across the question the same way you did.

Comment: @KevinB - thanks.  Just working to help improve the community, and want to understand when it appears I'm off-track....

Comment: I have a sneaky suspician that this question was created with the purpose of being a canonical post.

Comment: @cale_b Considering you said the answer was improved, presumably the comments became obsolete, and as such could be deleted.

Comment: im sorry you found my answer so lacking, you were free to edit it or answer yourself.

Comment: "I'd love to hear what I should have done differently" answer it yourself, or walk away

Comment: @Dagon - ok, just looked at your profile.  `Grumpy 4[0-9] year old hack programmer` - that's me too (literally), so I get it.  Funny....

Comment: comments are not for discussions, i keep getting told this, expect them to be deleted.

Comment: And I find it **tremendously ironic** that your *only question* on SO meta is almost this exact same question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318900/moderator-deleting-comments

Comment: Comments are not for **extended** discussion.... :) (which I'm doing, I apologize)

Comment: well EXACTLY expect comments to be deleted. expect on meta

Comment: I started flagging all the comments in this thread as obsolete, but then I realized that would be more annoying than funny if they all actually got deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A moderator deleted them.

Moderators are like the noonday sun to a comment's morning dew. You should consider comments transient, and if you care about something you write lasting, put it in an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  While I don't love the consequences of this answer, it puts a clear point on what I was asking.  It's interesting that the mod deleted them, sometimes before they were "clarified" (IMO), but good to understand.